# Mail opens on background

Tags: pantheon-mail

When there is some maximized window (browser, LibreOffice etc.) and i try to open Mail (from Plank or from new mail notification), it opens on background and on the bottom right corner of the screen, not in the middle. I have to minimize any window or open Mail on new workspace to avoid it. Any idea how to open it on the top and in the middle of the screen?